# How to calculate the distance between coordinate data by date?

Tags: r, coordinates, distance

My data is of the form:

```
* date        lat      long
* 01/01/13    47        118
* 01/01/13    48        119
* 01/01/13    47        118
* 02/01/13    46        119
* 02/01/13    46        119
* 02/01/13    48        118
```

I want to be able to calculate the distances between the points by date e.g. for 01/01/13, how far it is from the first row to the second and then from the second to the third etc. 
My actual data has more than 3 points per date.

The function

```
earth.dist(lats, dist = TRUE)
```

does this but will calculate the distances between dates as well. Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(data.table)
DT <- as.data.table(YourDataFrame)

DT[, earth.dist(c(lat, long)), by=date]
```

Comment: no prob.  Have a look at the vignette and FAQ that come with the data.table package, as the syntax is different from that of data.frame